# Is it possible to have dynamic values in tiles.xml in Struts2

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to pass dynamic values in tiles.xml as we do in struts.xml in Struts2? I have used ${parameter} to get dynamic values in config file but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic values"? What do you want to be dynamic?

Comment: I have set the parameter value using getter/setter in the interceptor and then in the tiles I used the following

<definition name="online.template" template="brand.jsp">
<put-attribute name="header" value="${id}/header.ftl"/>

Each client has different header files so I want to provide the id to direct to the right header. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just access the value in the Free Marker template as usual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass wildcards to tiles from your struts actions, I've used this to do similar things for dynamic projects where each client might have a different CSS file for instance.

In your struts action you would have a tiles result type and you can pass the value such as:

```
<action name="{eventURL}/update" class="org.groundworkgroup.struts.actions.admin.UpdateEventSettings">
    <result name="login" type="tiles">/login.tiles</result>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">/admin.${#session.bean.pageID}.${#session.bean.fileID}.tiles</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">/admin.${#session.bean.pageID}.${#session.bean.fileID}.tiles</result>
</action>
```

And then in your tiles.xml you would "plug in" the wildcards:

```
<definition name="/admin.*.*.tiles" extends="adminLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
    <put-attribute name="jsfile" value="{1}/js/{2}.js" />
    <put-attribute name="cssfile" value="{1}/css/{2}.css" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/content/sites/admin/main.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/content/sites/admin/menu.jsp" />
</definition>
```

In this particular example the struts action pageID is the project directory where the files are located and in the tiles.xml it is placed as wildcard {1}. The fileID is the filename associated with this particular action or user represented in the tiles.xml by {2}. You can use this set up to pass dynamic values to your tiles in order to control for example page states or JSP's to render or like in this example, custom css and js files.

Comment: seems like it might work but have one issue.. I am supposed to send the parameter to the template.. ie in the tiles code you showed it extends adminLayout. I want to send values to that adminLayout. How do I do that? any idea.

Comment: This is how my adminLayout looks..                     <definition name="online.template" template="/brand/brand.jsp" scope="request">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Project 1" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/index.html"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.ftl"/>
        <put-attribute name="logo" value="/logo.ftl"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.ftl"/>
    </definition>

Comment: I used viewpreparer and it worked. I wanted to know if it possible to access files like html from the tomcat/shared folder into my web-app. If yes, then will i have to restart tomcat when i place a file into the shared folder of tomcat?

Comment: Not sure. I would suggest opening a new question for tomcat/struts perhaps. The question is out of scope from this discussion and you'll have a better chance of response there.