# Multiple Tiles Definition Files OR Passing Parameters to tiles.xml at Runtime

Tags: struts2, tiles

Is there any way to define a new tiles definition file other than the `tiles.xml` file at runtime (say `tiles2.xml`) and use it? I want to create a `tiles2.xml` using Java when a action is called. **Or**, can I pass the `filename.jsp` as a parameter to `tiles.xml` during runtime?

Here is what I am trying to do.

There are 50 menus. When any of the menus is clicked, parameters regarding the menu name are passed through an action to a Java class. The class checks and finds which file to open. Now, either I can pass that value to `tiles.xml` or create a new tiles definition file.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600033/is-it-possible-to-have-dynamic-values-in-tiles-xml-in-struts2